# Getting controller input in c# windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am building a c# windows forms application in witch i need to get input from a controller.
I have found i can use Windows.Gaming.Input namespace to generate and access controller objects.
I am following this documentation page (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/raw-game-controller) and i am currently trying to get button labels of a controller using this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Windows.Gaming.Input;

namespace controllerTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        RawGameController Controller;
        int buttonCount;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            RawGameController.RawGameControllerAdded += 
FlightStick_FlightSickAdded;
            RawGameController.RawGameControllerRemoved += 
FlightStick_FlightSickRemoved;

        }

        private async void FlightStick_FlightSickAdded(object 
sender, RawGameController e)
        {
            await Log("Controller Added");

            Controller = 
RawGameController.RawGameControllers.First();
            buttonCount = Controller.ButtonCount;

            for (int i = 0; i < buttonCount; i++)
            {
                await 
Log(Controller.GetButtonLabel(i).ToString());
            }
        }

        private async void FlightStick_FlightSickRemoved(object 
sender, RawGameController e)
        {
            await Log("Controller Removed");
        }

        private async Task Log (string txt)
        {
            Task t = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() 
 + ": " + txt);
            });
            await t;
        }
    }
}
```

I know that Windows.Gaming.Input offers creating and using a "Gamepad" object but you can only use that with xbox controller but i am using a dualshock 4 controller so i am forced to use "RawGamingController" object.
When i plug in the controller, it is detected successfully, and i can get the number of buttons the controller has using Controller.ButtonCount method.
The problem is when i try to get button labels using the for loop i get this result:

16/02/2022: Controller Added
16/02/2022: None
16/02/2022: None
16/02/2022: None
16/02/2022: None
16/02/2022: None
16/02/2022: None
16/02/2022: None
16/02/2022: None
16/02/2022: None
16/02/2022: None
16/02/2022: None
16/02/2022: None
16/02/2022: None
16/02/2022: None

So the for loop only returns "none" as button labels and according to the documentation it should return this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.gaming.input.gamecontrollerbuttonlabel?view=winrt-22000.

I have tried using a different non ps4 controller and it still returns "none" as button labels. Am I doing something wrong in the code or is it the problem with the controllers?

Comment: Do not post an image of code. Post the code as text instead. We can't easily copy/paste/edit code in images, nor can it be indexed for searching. And it wastes bandwidth to convey the same info, and some people have the image hosting site blocked.

Comment: looks like your buttons dont have labels accoiated with them. It states here: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/uwp/api/windows.gaming.input.rawgamecontroller.getbuttonlabel?view=winrt-22000 
that:
You can create your own buttons array and then populate it with values representing each button's state using RawGameController.GetCurrentReading. See Raw game controller for more information.